# Setting render layers with shading masks with Maya Python

Tags: python, maya

So I'm trying to write a script that takes the name of materials from a list, creates a render layer named after each material, then applies a white surface shader to materials that share the render layer's name and a black surface shader to objects that don't.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

matName = ['blue_mat', 'green_mat', 'red_mat', 'purple_mat']

cmds.shadingNode('surfaceShader',asShader=True,n='WhiteMat')
cmds.setAttr('WhiteMat.outColor', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, type = 'double3')
cmds.shadingNode('surfaceShader',asShader=True,n='BlackMat')
cmds.setAttr('BlackMat.outColor', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, type = 'double3')

for i in range(4):
    cmds.select(cl=True)
    cmds.select( hi=True, all=True)
    cmds.createRenderLayer(n=matName[i]+'_layer')
    cmds.hyperShade(objects=matName[i])
    cmds.hyperShade(assign='BlackMat')
    if cmds.hyperShade(objects='BlackMat'):
        cmds.hyperShade(objects=matName[i])
```

So far, I've gotten it to create the layers with all objects and apply the black shader to everything, but I'm a bit lost on how to apply the white shader to a material on only the layer it's named after.  I think I can use an if statement to set it up, but I'm new to Python and still trying to get a handle on things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

alright, got it figured out.  Just had to change a few things, and include an `if else` inside a `range` to apply the shaders in the right order.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

#Put in your material names here.  Make sure they have the EXACT SAME spelling, caps, 
#and name conventions as in the Hypershade.  And don't forget to put each one in ''!

matName = ['blue_mat','green_mat','red_mat','purple_mat']

cmds.shadingNode('surfaceShader',asShader=True,n='WhiteMat')
cmds.setAttr('WhiteMat.outColor', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, type = 'double3')
cmds.shadingNode('surfaceShader',asShader=True,n='BlackMat')
cmds.setAttr('BlackMat.outColor', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, type = 'double3')

for i in range(len(matName)):
    cmds.select(cl=True)
    cmds.select( ado=True)
    cmds.createRenderLayer(n=matName[i]+'_layer')

    cmds.hyperShade(objects=matName[i])
    cmds.editRenderLayerGlobals(crl=matName[i]+'_layer')    

    for x in range(len(matName)):
        if matName[x]!=matName[i]:
            cmds.hyperShade(objects=matName[x])
            cmds.hyperShade(assign='BlackMat')
        else:
           cmds.hyperShade(objects=matName[x])
           cmds.hyperShade(assign='WhiteMat')
```